# Solving the problem of UI not matching with all screens flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The photo below is my original example

[image: example]

But no matter how hard I try, I can't match the disc and the sword
I created the following example using the following codes, but when I open it on pages with different sizes, I have a problem.

[image]

```dart
class Songs_Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Songs_Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Songs_Screen> createState() => _Songs_ScreenState();
}

class _Songs_ScreenState extends State<Songs_Screen> {
  Color col = color1;
  bool perescol = false;
  double _currentSliderValue = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      color: color3,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color3, boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                      color: color1.withOpacity(0.30),
                      blurRadius: 30)
                ]),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                      color: color1,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Songs',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: color1,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                      color: color1,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    BoxButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.playlist_add,
                        color: color1,
                      ),
                      ontop: () {},
                    ),
                    // BoxButton('assets/playlist.png'),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Song Name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: color1,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 24.0),
                        ),
                        Text('Artist Name',
                            style: TextStyle(color: color1, fontSize: 18.0))
                      ],
                    ),
                    BoxButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        IconlyLight.heart,
                        color: col,
                      ),
                      ontop: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (!perescol) {
                            col = color1;
                          } else {
                            col = Colors.red;
                          }
                          perescol = !perescol;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: size.width,
                height: size.height / 2.2,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      // left: 20,
                      // top: size.height / 29,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: size.width / 20, top: size.height / 40),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/disk2.png',
                          width: size.width / 1.4,
                          height: size.height / 2.8,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      // left: 150,
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width / 2.1),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/grmaphone.png',
                          width: size.width / 2,
                          height: size.height / 4,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: size.height / 10,
                      left: size.width / 1.2,
                      child: RotatedBox(
                        quarterTurns: 3,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            child: SliderTheme(
                              data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                                // trackShape: const RoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
                                trackHeight: 10.0,
                                activeTrackColor: color1,
                                showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
                                inactiveTickMarkColor: color4,
                                thumbColor: color2,
                                thumbShape: SquareSliderComponentShape(15, 20),
                                trackShape: MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape(0.2),
                                overlayColor: color4.withAlpha(32),
                                overlayShape:
                                    RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 20),
                              ),
                              child: Slider(
                                value: _currentSliderValue,
                                max: 100,
                                // divisions: 5,
                                // label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
                                onChanged: (double value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _currentSliderValue = value;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An example from another page :

[image]

[image]

I tried other methods like giving fixed value but my problem here was that the values were more or less than some screens.

Comment: Can you include full scaffold ?

Comment: sure I edited now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing full width, provide a flexible width that will fit  the disc and the sword.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: size.width > 600 ? 600 : size.width,
  height: 500,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: // disk,
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: // sword image,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

If you top level stack, use another stack. Also try to position the way you want, `Aling` can be replaced with `Positioned` widget

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the positioning of the sword with padding left. It should be the same as the disc plus a constant.

So, instead of

```dart
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width / 2.1),
```

It should be:

```dart
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width / 20 + 100),
```

You just need to adjust the constant `100` above.